# Pandas is not Reading Entire .CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been testing some issues I've had with Pandas. My end goal here is to add data to a .csv. While figuring out ways to change a .csv, I settled on this method:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv')

data.iat[1,1] = 'DataHere'

data.to_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

This code worked somewhat correctly. `DataHere` goes to the second row and second column, which is correct (because [0,0] is the first row and column. Note: it's not the normal x,y coordinates, it's more like y,x).

test.csv before code (6x6):

```
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
```

test.csv after code (6x5):

```
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,DataHere,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
```

It gets rid of the lowermost row for some reason! So I did some messing with the parameters of `pandas.read_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv')` to fix this problem, and got this:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv', nrows=6, skip_blank_lines=False)
```

I added `nrows=6` to make it read **6** rows, although I do intend to make it higher in the future. I added `skip_blank_lines=False` because I want to be able to add data to blank cells.

When I ran this new code (after changing the csv to its previous 6x6 state), it didn't help. It still erases the 6th row.

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv', nrows=6, skip_blank_lines=False)

data.iat[1,1] = 'DataHere'

data.to_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

I also tried `data.iat[6,3] = 'DataHere'` instead of `data.iat[1,1] = 'DataHere'`, which returned this error:

```
IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

This shows that not only it is erasing the last row, but that it cannot add data to a blank cell. To make sure that it was the fault of this line: `data = pandas.read_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv', nrows=6, skip_blank_lines=False)`, I put `print(data)` in the line immediately after it and got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51khT.png) output (plus the previously stated errors). There should be a 5th row of 'yes' there. So my two problems are:

1. Deletion of a row.
2. Not being able to add data to a blank cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv')` uses the first row as a header row. Your `test.csv` does not have a header row.  So it is likely that the first row (data row) in `test.csv` is being read as a header row.  Giving you 5 data rows and not 6 as you expect.

**This could be happening**

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO(
'''yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes
yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes'''
)

data = pd.read_csv(sim_csv)
print(data)

   yes yes.1 yes.2 yes.3 yes.4 yes.5
0  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
1  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
2  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
3  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
4  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
```

Then when you write out the CSV with `to_csv(header=None)` you lose that first row of data.

To get around this you could do:

```
pandas.read_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv', header=None)
```

or you could do this:

```
pandas.to_csv('path/to/my/script/test.csv')
```

Just make sure that you're consistent with `header=None`, you either set both `pandas.read_csv` and `pandas.to_csv` to `header=None`, or just remove it, don't have `header=None` on one or the other.

**Adding a row (cell to a new row)**

You can add a row (cell to a row) by using the index. For example if you had:

```
   yes yes.1 yes.2 yes.3 yes.4 yes.5
0  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
1  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
2  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
3  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
4  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
```

Then you could do:  (note that this is `.at` and not `.iat`)

```
df.at[5,'yes'] = 'yes'
```

Which will give you:

```
   yes yes.1 yes.2 yes.3 yes.4 yes.5
0  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
1  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
2  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
3  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
4  yes   yes   yes   yes   yes   yes
5  yes   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: @SmortVarke I updated my answer to answer your questions above

Comment: I fixed my problem by removing ``header=False`` because then it takes into account that the first row is headers, and therefore ``data.iat[0,0] = 'DataHere'`` places ``'DataHere'`` at [1,0], so it all adds up to 6 rows. This also fixes the fact that it was erasing rows. I think it would try to read it with a header, then write it without a header, causing the erasing of a line. Ultimately you got me to understand though by pointing out that the "missing" row is the header xD